# Using EF 5.x DbContext Fluent Generator but properties are not virtual

Tags: entity-framework, templates, poco, entity-framework-5

I used the EF 5.x DbContext Fluent Generator to generate my POCO classes but my properties are not coded as virtual.  Don't you have to have that for tracking to occur?  Why wouldn't the template already use virtual for properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we found that for the majority of users it was better to use snapshot change tracking rather than change tracking proxies. Change tracking proxies have their place in certain situations, but usually they add complexity without any real benefit.  For more info see http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/11/24/why-are-the-dbcontext-t4-templates-so-different-from-the-ef4-poco-templates/ and http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/